# AS3 BitmapData.compare() function

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone tell me what is the practical use of the BitmapData.compare() function in AS3:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare()

I have a few in my list, but I believe I have yet to exhaust it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228929/compare-two-bitmaps-in-actionscript-3/12230200#12230200

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to make a camera detector. You compare the old version with the new version and if the differences are greater than the minimum acceptable, then...there you go :)

I used it to test if the webcam was working or not. Skype got it and in flash, it was basically a black screen input, so I tested two snapshots and compared them and they where equal (and a solid black color).